# HtmlAgilityPack HtmlWeb.Load throws error: Error getting response stream (ReadDoneAsync2): ReceiveFailure

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Hey so I am just going:

```
HtmlWeb web2 = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web2.Load(myURL);
```

and it is returning an error for me on [this website](https://parahumans.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/gestation-1-2/) but works on others.

The error is: "Error getting response stream (ReadDoneAsync2): ReceiveFailure"

I can't find any documentation on that error, is there something I am doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: Try this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mu9iMP

Comment: Edit - I added the whole stack trade to the question

Comment: @RandRandom, this ended up working. Could you explain what the issue is with the original method?

Comment: I can only speculate, but I would imagine that htmlagilitypack may use an outdated version for the webrequest eg. Not HTTP2 support or something in that regard. So, I gave it a try to manually download the html.